# I'm having issues getting the webview working for a contextual add-in I'm building for Outlook

Tags: xml, webview, outlook, add-in, outlook-web-addins

The add-in should detect and highlight a specific URL using regex match (and it does this part) and when a user clicks on the detected area a webview should pop-up and display the webpage from the link. But it's not doing that.It's always saying that Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>02d1356d-95ba-466a-9eb8-91e37dac827e</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Outlook add-In"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A Outlook add-in."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/src/taskpane/index.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>

  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="UURL" RegExValue="https://google\.com/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext"/>
                
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="UURL2" 
  RegExValue="google\.com/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <!-- VersionOverrides for the v1.1 schema -->
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- DetectedEntity -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="DetectedEntity">
              <Label resid="contextLabel" />
              <SourceLocation resid="detectedEntityURL" />
              <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">                                            
                <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message"/>
                  <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="UURL" RegExValue="https://google\.com/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext"/>
                
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="UURL2" 
  RegExValue="google\.com/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext"/>
<!--I have to use 2 Rules using AND because contextual add-ins do not directly work with urls -->
            </Rule>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>

      <Resources>
      
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
    
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="detectedEntityURL" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/src/taskpane/index.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="contextLabel" DefaultValue="my outlook add-in "/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed the following rules chained with `AND` operator:

```
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">                                            
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message"/>
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="UURL" RegExValue="https://google\.com/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext"/>
              
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="UURL2" 
  RegExValue="google\.com/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext"/>
<!--I have to use 2 Rules using AND because contextual add-ins do not directly work with urls -->
</Rule>
```

So, I'd suggest playing with a single regex condition. If it doesn't work correctly either, you may try filing an issue on the `officejs` repo at github. Or just try using the sample add-in at https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-In-Contextual-Regex/blob/master/contoso-order-number-manifest.xml .

Also you need to make sure the `detectedEntityURL` file is available online.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eugene.I think I have found the problem,I am not able to access any of my files from the localhost server,even though the localhost server is running .I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: It seems the `detectedEntityURL` was not accessible. Then it makes sense to mark the answer.